# excel copy data in many columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have this Excel macro:

```
Sub test()
     Dim LR As Long, i As Long, buf
     LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 3 To LR
     If Cells(i, 25).Value <> "" Then
     buf = Cells(i, 25).Value
     Else
     Cells(i, 25).Value = buf
     End If
     Next
End Sub
```

This helps me to do this in the DAT 1 column:

```
ID      LABEL   DAT 1   DAT 2   DAT 3   DAT 4   DAT 5   DAT 6   DAT 7
1330102 10171   12:02   12:08   13:00   14:24   14:40   15:30   16:28
1329807 9598    11:57   12:20   13:05   14:10   14:22   15:02   15:35
1329807 9598    11:57                       
1329807 9598    11:57                       
1331864 9608    15:49   16:02   16:12   17:13   17:25   18:56   19:14
1329708 9608    15:49                       
5001021 98327   13:30   13:22   13:32   14:09   14:19   14:54   15:13
1307566 98327   13:30                       
1306925 98327   13:30                       
1307574 98327   13:30
```

I need to do this: (copy the same value in multiple columns and rows).
DAT 2, DAT 3, DAT 4, DAT 5, DAT 6, DAT 7.

```
ID      LABEL   DAT 1   DAT 2   DAT 3   DAT 4   DAT 5   DAT 6   DAT 7
1330102 10171   12:02   12:08   13:00   14:24   14:40   15:30   16:28
1329807 9598    11:57   12:20   13:05   14:10   14:22   15:02   15:35
1329807 9598    11:57   12:20   13:05   14:10   14:22   15:02   15:35       
1329807 9598    11:57   12:20   13:05   14:10   14:22   15:02   15:35
1331864 9608    15:49   16:02   16:12   17:13   17:25   18:56   19:14
1329708 9608    15:49   16:02   16:12   17:13   17:25   18:56   19:14       
5001021 98327   13:30   13:22   13:32   14:09   14:19   14:54   15:13
1307566 98327   13:30   13:22   13:32   14:09   14:19   14:54   15:13
1306925 98327   13:30   13:22   13:32   14:09   14:19   14:54   15:13
1307574 98327   13:30   13:22   13:32   14:09   14:19   14:54   15:13
```

Any ideas for implementing the solution...?

Answer (score 0):

Loop across the columns, and loop across the rows within that loop?

```
Sub test()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim c As Long
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' Assuming row 2 is your headers
    For c = 25 To LC  ' Assuming that column Y is first column to be processed
        For i = 3 To LR
            If Cells(i, c).Value = "" Then
                Cells(i, c).Value = Cells(i - 1, c).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much YowE3K, this works like a charm and easiest that my implementation.